# Why the flutter switch onChanged callback triggers wrong?

Tags: flutter, dart, toggle, uiswitch, selectionchanged

Initially the flutter switch widget has the value false. After I swipe, the switch is true. But if I swipe again, the onChange method is not triggered.

I use setState() to change the value of the switch as onChanged method. I tried to hand the BuildContext over, but no success.

```dart
    bool value = false;

    void _setValue(bool value) {
        print('before: ' + this.value.toString());
        setState(() => this.value = value);
        print('after: ' + this.value.toString());
    }

    Widget _getSwitch() {
       return Switch(
              value: this.value,
              onChanged: _setValue,
       );
    }
```

## expected result:

**Initially false, and switch to true.**

I/flutter (20662): before: false

I/flutter (20662): after: true

**switch to false**

I/flutter (20662): before: true

I/flutter (20662): after: false

**switch to true**

I/flutter (20662): before: false

I/flutter (20662): after: true

## actual result:

**Initially false, and now I switch to true.**

I/flutter (20662): before: false

I/flutter (20662): after: true

**So far so great!**

**Now I switch to false... Nothing happened. => no onChanged call**

**Now I switch to true and this is the output:**

I/flutter (20662): before: true

I/flutter (20662): after: true

**Makes no sense!?**

Answer (score 0):

I created an object

```dart
   Switch switch2;

   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    switch2 = _getSwitch();
  }
```

Then I tried to build() the switch, instead I just call the method _getSwitch in build() directly.